# Large database table queries return empty set

Tags: mysql, database, query, mysql5, mysql5.5

I'm trying to understand a weird problem with a MySQL database on one of my websites.

When I loaded a big set of data from a CSV file (2,200,000 records with a single column, using `LOAD DATA`) into a table, my application started to misbehave.

After some time looking at the malfunctioning, I found out that some queries on that big table aren't working as expected.

I've tried the simplest query possibile to look for a certain entry in that table: querying for a certain value (that I know it's present) for a `varchar(45)` primary key column (ex. `SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name = "string_value"`). Surprisingly the server returned me an empty set.
I also tried `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE column_name = "string_value"` and it, returned zero.

When I do a similar look-up for a value in a similar table (but with just a couple entries), the query works correctly and returns me a single row.

My question: is it possible that this case is some kind of bug with the MySQL database server?

I'm using MySQL version 5.6.35-80.0-log.

The two example tables structure contain two columns: a `varchar(45)` primary key and a `bit(1)` "boolean".
The first column contains code string consisting of alphanumeric characters

Comment: I've seen numerous developers struggle  with meaningful (trailing) white space or similar "invisible characters"  in table names, column names and data i.e `"name-value "` != `"name-value"`, which is a typo that admittedly can be quite hard to spot with many tools.

Comment: Your question is exclusively predicated on the content of the data - which we know nothing about. What does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name` tell you?

Comment: @symcbean I updated the question and added my own answer

Comment: @HBruijn thanks you were right about trailing white space. PhpMyAdmin failed to detect the correct line endings of the imported CSV file and I had trailing carriage-return characters in the code strings

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
When importing the CSV, PhpMyAdmin was detecting the wrong line endings and the records had a trailing carriage-return character